# recyclerView child won't be clickable after putting recyclerView in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a recyclerView which I implemented a listener for its child in ViewHolder class just like this:

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun binding(model: NewsAdapterModel) {


            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onClick.onClick(model.id)
            }
}
```

and use this code for my onBindViewHolder:

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding(items[position])
    }
```

also here is my xml code which contains recyclerView and a SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".main.news.NewsFragment">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loading">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loading" />

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

my problem is as soon as I put my recyclerView inside Swipe Refreshing layout, item of recycler view are not clickable anymore. when I remove swipe refresh layout it become clickable again,
how can I solve this issue?

Comment: try making both swiperefresh and recyclerView matxh parent

Comment: @Rinat, no, nothing changed

Comment: this might sound stupid, but you never know.. Try adding android:clickable="false" to swiperefreshLayout

Comment: Any luck with this one?

Answer (score 0):

You should use SwipeRefreshLayout as parent of your LinearLayout and notify recycle view on setOnRefreshListener, code as follows-

**Main Layout File**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data></data>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loading">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".main.news.NewsFragment">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loading" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</layout>
```

Doing so you can choose to show progress base until your recycle view will be updated with new information.

**SwipeRefreshListener**

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
    new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");

            // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
            // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
            myUpdateOperation();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I changed my layout but nothing changed. I also should mention my problem is with clicking on recyclerView child not refreshing SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: I was getting similar result because my recycle view item was clickable, it was a mistake. I am not able to reproduce the issue, I added RecycleView inside SwipeGestureLayout and it was working fine. Please check if you are setting any click listener on SwipeGestureLayout.